# How to reset to local mongodb with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

We have a production Meteor deployment with corresponding MongoDB instance. I connected to it from my machine to run a maintenance script. Now I'm trying to reset Meteor locally to connection to the local MongoDB instance. I thought `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor` would work, but I get `Exception in callback of async function: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:3001]`. I haven't changed Meteor's default port, so it should still be running on 3000, and I thought the DB would listen on 3001. I can't tell if `meteor reset` would do the job, or if that would instead nuke the production DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor starts the local MongoDB instance when you invoke `meteor`, which is why it can't connect. Try unsetting `MONGO_URL` and starting meteor normally.

```
unset MONGO_URL
meteor
```